# How to provide regular variable to Scope Resolution Operator

Tags: php, php-ews

```
$version = \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Client::$ews_version;
```

Throws

> Uncaught Error: Access to undeclared static property:

Where `$ews_version` is a client provided variable with possible values of:

```
$ews_version = 'VERSION_2007';
$ews_version = 'VERSION_2007_SP1';
$ews_version = 'VERSION_2009';
$ews_version = 'VERSION_2010';
$ews_version = 'VERSION_2010_SP1';
$ews_version = 'VERSION_2010_SP2';
$ews_version = 'VERSION_2013';
$ews_version = 'VERSION_2013_SP1';
$ews_version = 'VERSION_2016';
```

Providing const manually, works fine:

```
$version = \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Client::VERSION_2013_SP1;
```

Please help. Thanks.

Code:

```
$ews_version = $_REQUEST['version']; // User posted version (i.e. VERSION_2009)

// Set connection information.
$host = $ews_host;
$username = $ews_username;
$password = $ews_password;
$version = \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Client::$ews_version;

$client = new \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Client($host, $username, $password, $version);
```

Comment: Where in the [source code](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/blob/master/src/Client.php) do you see that variable defined publically and statically? It's not there, just like the error said.

Comment: Why do I need to define is as static or public? It's a regular variable outside of any classes or functions. Please see my edit

Comment: The Client Class defines a `$version` variable that is `protected`, which means you can't access it in this case. It's also an instance variable and not defined statically, so you can't access it the way you are trying. If you want to get the version of the client, you will have to modify that class to have a public getVersion function that returns this variable.

Comment: What are my options?

Comment: https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/pull/380

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to access a constant using a variable.

You can solve this using reflection:

```
$ews_version = 'VERSION_2007';
$ref = new ReflectionClass(\jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Client::class);
$version = $ref->getConstant($ews_version);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for